# Columns in PIVOT not in a desired sequence

Tags: t-sql, pivot

I just started working with `SQL PIVOT` and have a issues with ordering of the columns and was courious as to how to correct it. I've sifted through several PIVOT related post here and on other sites but nothing immediatelly struck as relevant.

You'll notice I've added a hard-coded OrderBy files in each query but that doesn't help, I think it's the [Description] field that the pitot is sorting the columns on. So presently the columns appear from left to right in the following order:

***[Fee Period], [Excellent], [Good], [No of Interim], [Satisfactory], [Unsatisfactory], [Very Good]***.

Instead I need the following order:

***[Fee Period], [No of Interim], [Excellent], [Very Good],[Good],[Satisfactory], [Unsatisfactory]***.

I'm beginning to think it may not be a pure pivot issue - never the less I could use some help, thanks.

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED

SELECT @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + [Description] 
FROM dbo.vQualScoringGrade 
ORDER BY '],[' + [Description] FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') + ']'

SET @query = N'SELECT [Fee Period], ' + @cols + ' FROM 
(SELECT [Award Fee Period],GradeCount, Description, Value, OrderBy FROM 
dbo.vQualScoringGrade) p
PIVOT (SUM([Value]) for [Description] IN ( ' + @cols + ' )) AS pvt ORDER BY [Fee Period]'

execute(@query)
```

The view [vQualScoringGrade] that feeds the sproc looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT [Fee Period], GradeCount, Description, 
GradeCount AS Value, OrderBy
FROM (SELECT [Fee Period], 'No of Interim' AS Description, COUNT(VerNumber) AS GradeCount, 1 AS
OrderBy
FROM dbo.vQualScoringExcellent AS vQualScoringExcellent
GROUP BY GIIANumber, Description
UNION
SELECT [Fee Period], 'Excellent' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS GradeCount, 2 AS OrderBy
FROM dbo.vQualScoringExcellent AS vQualScoringExcellent_1
GROUP BY VerNumber, Description
UNION
SELECT [Fee Period], 'Very Good' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS GradeCount, 3 AS OrderBy
FROM dbo.vQualScoringVeryGood AS vQualScoringVeryGood
GROUP BY VerNumber, Description
UNION
SELECT [Fee Period], 'Good' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS GradeCount, 4 AS OrderBy
FROM dbo.vQualScoringGood AS vQualScoringGood
GROUP BY VerNumber, Description
UNION
SELECT [Fee Period], 'Satisfactory' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS GradeCount, 5 AS
OrderBy
FROM dbo.vQualScoringSatisfactory AS vQualScoringSatisfactory
GROUP BY VerNumber, Description
UNION
SELECT [Fee Period], 'Unsatisfactory' AS Description, COUNT(Description) AS GradeCount, 6 AS OrderBy
FROM dbo.vQualScoringUnsatisfactory AS vQualScoringUnsatisfactory
GROUP BY VerNumber, Description) AS QualScoringGrade
ORDER BY OrderBy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT '],[' + [Description] 
    FROM dbo.vQualScoringGrade 
    GROUP BY [Description] 
    ORDER BY MAX([orderby]), [Description] 
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') + ']'
```

Answer (score 0):

You specified that you wanted the columns in alphabetical order here:

```
SELECT @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + [Description] 
  FROM dbo.vQualScoringGrade 
  ORDER BY '],[' + [Description] FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') + ']'
```

by adding an `ORDER BY` clause.

If each description had an associated column order field you could sort on that to get an explicit order.

Aside: Usually the order of columns returned from a query isn't critical.  The application consuming the data is responsible for formatting the data.  That owuld include displaying it in a suitable order.

Comment: If I take out the `Order by` the whole thnig breaks.

Comment: @Risho - Are you saying that you tried `SELECT @cols = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + [Description] FROM dbo.vQualScoringGrade FOR XML PATH('')), 1,2,'') + ']'`?  Can you be more specific than _the whole thnig breaks_?

Comment: I get `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '],[' to data type int.` If I understands this `PIVOT` code correctly, this part is what build the columns headers from my data, which is [Description].